# how to use kubernetes lib to watch all events

Tags: events, kubernetes

guys
I want to watch all kubernetes events and I find the source code here: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/informers/events/v1beta1/event.go

However, I can not find any examples about how to use the functions.
Can anyone help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I’d like to collect the event logs with `kubectl` or REST API[2] as JSON, then you 
 can send the logs to `fluentd` for centralized monitoring such as Elasticsearch.

Here is a good sample;[0], though it's OpenShift, but if `oc` cmd replace with `kubectl` cmd, it's same with Kubernetes. (Yeah, OpenShift is Enterprise Kubernetes).

[1] is how to implement the `fluentd` - `Elasticsearch` stack.

I hope this help you.

- [0] [https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/security/monitoring.html#security-monitoring-events]
- [1] [https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/recipe-json-to-elasticsearch]
- [2] [https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#list-all-namespaces-292]

Answer (score 1):

One or several of these could help:

- "watches" for (quote) "...efficient change notifications on resources" - see [Kubernetes API Concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/) as well as the [API Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-reference) for a particular version. Example: `GET /api/v1/namespaces/test/pods?watch=1&resourceVersion=10245`
- Event [Read Operations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#-strong-read-operations-strong--291).
- `kubectl get` allows you to specify the -w or --watch flag to start watching updates to a particular object.

I believe the events are for a particular resource or collection of resources, not for all resources.